# How to merge a demographic variable spread across multiple columns into one column?

Tags: r

I'm currently working with a raw data export from a survey. I'm currently in the cleaning stages, and the way some of the demographic variables are structured isn't conducive for analysis. Specifically, there are multiple race options that respondents can select from, and the way it looks in the data export is like this:

[image]

Here is the code for replicating the dataset:

```
ID <- c(rep(c(1:8), 1))
White <- c("White",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"White","White")
Asian <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"Asian",NA,"Asian")
SouthAfrican <- c(NA,"SouthAfrican",NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, "SouthAfrican")
Hispanic <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Hispanic", "Hispanic", NA, NA)
WestAsian <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "WestAsian", NA)
PreferNotToAnswer <- c(NA, NA,"PreferNotToAnswer", "PreferNotToAnswer", NA, NA, NA, NA)

df <- data.frame(ID, White, Asian, SouthAfrican, Hispanic, WestAsian, PreferNotToAnswer)
```

What I would like to do is find a way create a "Race" column and merge the values in the separate columns into that one Race variable. If there are multiple options that a respondent selected as their race (i.e., ID 8), I would want to find a way to have the Race variable coded as "Mixed" for that respondent.

So the result I'm looking for is:

```
ID <- c(rep(c(1:8), 1))
White <- c("White",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"White","White")
Asian <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"Asian",NA,"Asian")
SouthAfrican <- c(NA,"SouthAfrican",NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, "SouthAfrican")
Hispanic <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Hispanic", "Hispanic", NA, NA)
WestAsian <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "WestAsian", NA)
PreferNotToAnswer <- c(NA, NA,"PreferNotToAnswer", "PreferNotToAnswer",NA, NA, NA, NA)
Race <- c("White","SouthAfrican","PreferNotToAnswer", "PreferNotToAnswer","Hispanic", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed")

df <- data.frame(ID, White, Asian, SouthAfrican, Hispanic,WestAsian,PreferNotToAnswer,Race)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `v`ector, define demographic variables, then make a boolean `m`atrix and look up `which.max` to subset your vector. Finally `replace` multiple answers where `rowSums` are greater than 1, and pipe it into another `replace` to care for the non-answers with `NA`s (would otherwise default to first element, i.e. White in this case).

```
v <- c("White", "Asian", "SouthAfrican", "Hispanic", "WestAsian", "PreferNotToAnswer")
m <- !is.na(df[v])
df$race <- replace(v[apply(m, 1, which.max)], rowSums(m) > 1, 'mixed') |>
  replace(rowSums(m) == 0, NA_character_)
#   ID White Asian SouthAfrican Hispanic WestAsian PreferNotToAnswer              race
# 1  1 White  <NA>         <NA>     <NA>      <NA>              <NA>             White
# 2  2  <NA>  <NA> SouthAfrican     <NA>      <NA>              <NA>      SouthAfrican
# 3  3  <NA>  <NA>         <NA>     <NA>      <NA> PreferNotToAnswer PreferNotToAnswer
# 4  4  <NA>  <NA>         <NA>     <NA>      <NA> PreferNotToAnswer PreferNotToAnswer
# 5  5  <NA>  <NA>         <NA> Hispanic      <NA>              <NA>          Hispanic
# 6  6  <NA> Asian         <NA> Hispanic      <NA>              <NA>             mixed
# 7  7 White  <NA>         <NA>     <NA> WestAsian              <NA>             mixed
# 8  8 White Asian SouthAfrican     <NA>      <NA>              <NA>             mixed
```

Note that this should be *much* faster than any approach that attempts to row-wise removing `NA`s.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a function which can do this directly, but I think it can be quickly done with dplyr.

I would do the following:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID,
               values_to = "race",
               values_drop_na = T) %>% 
  select(-name) %>% 
  summarise(race = ifelse(n() == 1, race,
                          "Mixed"),
              .by = ID)
```

Then, you will get the next data frame.

```
# A tibble: 8 × 2
     ID race             
  <int> <chr>            
1     1 White            
2     2 SouthAfrican     
3     3 PreferNotToAnswer
4     4 PreferNotToAnswer
5     5 Hispanic         
6     6 Mixed            
7     7 Mixed            
8     8 Mixed
```